# Chrome Web inspector shows unusual symbol when calling prototype method in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I have this function called "createGameObjectConstructor" which takes a function and a prototype adds the prototype and a method to the function then returns the function.It can be used like this

```
Monster = createGameObjectConstructor(function () {
    this.evilness = 9001;

}, {
    eatHuman:function () {
        console.log('human consumed');
    }, type:'scary'
});
```

and "createGameObjectConstructor" looks like this

```
createGameObjectConstructor = (function () {

    var recent = function () { //every actual object constructor will share this method
        return (instance.length> 0) ? instance[instance.length - 1] :null;
    };


    return function (constructor, prototype) { //createGameObjectConstructor

        var instanceArray = new Array();

        constructor.prototype = prototype;

        return function (){ //actual object's constructor
            var instance = new constructor();
            instance.constructor = constructor;
            instanceArray.push();
            return instance;
        };

        f.recent = recent;

        return f;

    }

}());
```

But when I call `Monster().eatHuman();` in Chrome's console it returns the function undefined but with a weird arrow next to it, is this because my bizarre coding somehow led it too eval the code or something?

[image: The Arrow]

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UZmL9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means the *return value* of the function is `undefined`.

All JavaScript functions [return `undefined` by default](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.1) if no explicit `return` statement is found.

```
function foo(){
    console.log("Hi");
}
foo(); // you will get the same 'undefined'
```

But

```
function foo(){
    console.log("Hi");
    return 5;
}
foo(); // you will get 5 with that arrow
```

Comment: So how come it doesn't appear when I call a prototype method using `function a(){}; a.prototype.b=function(){}; c=new a(); c.b();`

Comment: oh.. but it does when I add `console.log('something')` to the method. Guess it's just a chrome thing:) thanks!